# Executing repository method inside Spring Data Jpa @PostRemove is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `First` and `Second`. There are `@PreRemove` and `PostRemove` implementations for `First`. The `preRemove()` creates a record in `Second` and caches the result to a transient property `First.second`. This is working. I want the `postRemove` to update the same record, which is not working. It is not updating the record.

```
@Entity
@Getter@Setter@NoArgsConstructor@AllArgsConstructor
public class Second {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String prop;
}


@Entity
@Getter@Setter@NoArgsConstructor@AllArgsConstructor
public class First {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  private String prop;

  @Transient@JsonIgnore
  private Second second;

  @PreRemove
  public void preRemove() {
      second = MyBeanUtils.getBean(SecondRepository.class).save(new Second());
  }

  @PostRemove
  public void postRemove() {
      second.setProp("after remove");
      MyBeanUtils.getBean(SecondRepository.class).save(second);
  }

}
```

Controller and Repository codes

```
@Repository
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long> {
}
@Repository
public interface SecondRepository extends JpaRepository<Second, Long> {
}
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoController {

    private final FirstRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/first")
    public First postBo3(@RequestBody First bo3) {
        return repository.save(bo3);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/first/{id}")
    void postBo3(@PathVariable long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

When I put a break point on the line `second.setProp("after remove");` in the `postRemove()`, it shows the field `second` does have an ID, because it is the cached instance after `save()`.

With `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, these are the queries logged. Can't see any update query and the record is not updated in the database too. Please suggest a reason for this and a workaround.

```
Hibernate: select first0_.id as id1_0_0_, first0_.prop as prop2_0_0_ from first first0_ where first0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into second (prop) values (?)
Hibernate: delete from first where id=?
```

Comment: @PostRemove is "in transaction" so be careful.
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38870659/390462

Comment: @BendaThierry.com Yes `@PostRemove` is in transaction. I'm wondering why the second record is not updated then!

Comment: Simply because your transaction is closed before triggering this `@PostRemove` code. You'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@Transactional` annotation above any method involved in database operations in your (micro)services ensure you are staying inside a current database transaction.

Please stop using repositories in the controllers layer. It's a very bad way to develop things for your application.

Disable OpenSessionInView property to optimize things around your database queries.

Comment: I don't think the transaction is closed, otherwise, it would have returned an error. Here, it is not updating the record `second` even if the `@PostRemove` is executed without any error.
I tried this after making the function with `@DeleteMapping` transactional, but still the same behaviour.
I agree with you that we should not call repository methods inside controller. My actual project don't. Here I am using a sample for simplicity.

Comment: Using 
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)` may help, maybe ?

Comment: Maybe that is related to your `transient` field not saved by default in database. So JPA events are not supported by this kind of qualifier type.

Comment: Maybe it is related to `@RestController` and `@JsonIgnore` on that field. So your backend don't care about it and cannot manage it.